# AttributeError:' 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rolling' ' arises only after filtering the CSV data

Tags: python, csv, filter, mean

If I pass the value of `csv` data following the way given below it produces the output.

```
data = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
avg = data['A'].rolling(3).mean() 
print(avg)
```

But if pass the value via following the way given below it produces error.

```
dff=[]
dff1=[]
dff1=abs(data['A'])

b, a = scipy.signal.butter(2, 0.05, 'highpass')
dff = scipy.signal.filtfilt(b, a, dff1) 

avg = dff.rolling(3).mean() 
print(avg)
```

Error is:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rolling'

I can't figure it out, what is wrong with the code?

after applying `dff = pd.Dataframe(dff)`new  problem arises. one unexpected zero is displayed at the top.
[image]

What is the reason behind this? How to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`rolling` is a function on Pandas `Series` and `DataFrame`s. Scipy  knows nothing about these, and generates Numpy `ndarray`s as output. It can accept dataframes and series as *input*, because the Pandas types can mimic ndarrays when needed.

The solution might be as simple as re-wrapping the ndarray as a dataframe using

```
dff = pd.Dataframe(dff)
```

Comment: after applying dff = pd.Dataframe(dff) my previous problem has gone but new problem has been arised. One unexpted zero is displayed at the top of array. what's the reason behind this? Can you please tell me how to get rid of this issue? I have attached the output .

Comment: That zero is the column name. You could do `dff = pd.DataFrame(dff, columns=['A'])` to have it named `A` instead. Check the docs for details: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Okay.Thank you so much.